# Identify objects by index

Tags: watin

Is it possible to identify the objects by index in Watin ( just like selenium //input[2] )

e.g. if we have input fields

inputfield : << input id="userid" type="text">>

inputfield :<< input id="userid" type="text">>

inputfield : << input id="userid" type="text">>

inputfield : << input id="userid" type="text">>

How to identify each one by index?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is:

```
browser.TextFields.Filter(Find.ById("id_name"))[0];
```